# Is there a way to autoupdate symlinks?

Tags: software-installation, symbolic-link

If I have a file somewhere and move it somewhere, is there a method of making sure that all symbolic links that pointed to it are updated as well?

Something that's either like

```sh
mv --magic-option src dest
```

or

```sh
mv src dest
magic-command src dest
```

Comment: Not likely. Such symlinks could be anywhere on the filesystem (including places you wouldn't normally be able to reach if you're not root)

Comment: I'm willing to use `sudo`.

Comment: Such an option could exist and could reliably work only if the system had a central database of all symlinks, but there is no such thing. Symlinks are "one-way" only: if B is a symlink to A, then having only A there is no method to know that B points to it (other than searching the entire filesystem).

Comment: @raj: This involves traversing the complete directory tree, which is time-consuming, but trivial. Doing that all the time in my QDirStat. ;-)

Comment: The only way is to have a hard link instead of a symbolic link. That requires the source file, the hard link, and the destination to all be on the same file system, otherwise the link will be broken. (I'm not at my computer, so I can't test this, but I believe that in such a case, you'll end up with two independent copies of the file.)

Answer (score 1):

I am not aware of any standard Linux command for that.

This *could* be scripted, but it would be quite an involved script:

- Check the complete filesystem for symlinks pointing to the subtree that is about to be moved; store all those symlinks. Important: include relative symlinks (pointing to "../../....").
- Move / rename the subtree.
- Iterate over the stored symlinks and recreate them, now using the new path to that subtree. This might be non-trivial for relative symlinks.
- Restore the old owner and group for each link.

There is much potential for errors.

Comment: Also notice that this needs special handling for symlinks that are _inside_ the tree that is moved.